# Bootstrap 4 (Jquery ?) - nav-items in mobile menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've made navbar using Bootstrap4 and when I open website as mobile screen links in menu doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark" style="background-color: #E2BA28">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.example.com"><img src="logo" width="60" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""></a>

        <!-- Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link eak-link" href="https://www.example.com">example</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link eak-link" href="https://www.example.com">example</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link eak-link" href="#">example</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link eak-link" href="https://www.example.com">example</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link eak-link eak-abc" href="https://www.example.com">example</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

If it does help I'm using this js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.nav-item').hover(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('animated bounceIn')
      });
});
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: What do you mean by _"links do not work"_?

Comment: I'm clicking them and they doesn't do anything.

Comment: You missed a closing `div` tag before the closing `nav` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding bootstrap's js code at the footer of your page, you'll need to also include`jQuery`.

Here's a working pen:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayKYzW)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work too. But when I disable my js with animated.css it's working, so it is possible to disable my js when screen size is lower than 600 px width ?